# MANY_MANY relationships in plugins

Tags: plugin-development, database

I replicated what was mentioned here: ([Plugins: Managing Related Records](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/plugins-managing-related-records/1739#1739))

However I'm not seeing any new table created to on plugin install.

I have a "LeaderRecord" with

```
'trips'     => [static::MANY_MANY, 'pluginexample_TripRecord', 'pluginexample_trip_leaders(tripId, leaderId)']
```

with the same relation defined in a "TripRecord", am I missing something to have the tabled created?

Thanks!

Comment: First – your record(s) _will only create tables when the plugin is first installed_, so if your plugin is already installed, you'll need to un- and reinstall it. Secondly, I believe your record's class name (second parameter) should be ```PluginExample_TripRecord```.

Comment: I only used that name to obfuscate clients name - It is capitalized in actual. I have uninstalled and re-installed and still don't seem to be getting the PluginExample_trip_leaders table.

Comment: I might've misinterpreted your issue - both tables needs their own record. Simply defining relations in one record won't create another table.

Comment: If you already have two record classes, I'd suggest adding them both – in full – to your question, it'll probably make figuring out your issue much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft won't create the join table for you when specifying a MANY_MANY relationship.  You'll still need to manually create a record for that join table.  See Craft's own `craft/app/records/UserGroup_UserRecord.php` as an example.

What it will do, as [mentioned in the answer you linked to](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/plugins-managing-related-records/1739#1739) is keep the data up-to-date in the join table without having to specifically reference it in your queries.